# FluentD datetime format doesn't match

Tags: regex, fluentd

This is my FluentD parser config:

```
<filter format.3.**>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  @type parser                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  format /^\[(?<module>[^\]]+)\] (?<time>.+): (?<msg>.*)$/                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  key_name log                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  keep_time_key true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  reserve_data false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</filter>
```

And that's an example log line:

```
[Macaron] 2017-04-26 16:54:26: Started GET / for 172.20.0.0
```

In the FluentD error log I'm getting:

```
2017-04-27 12:01:58 +0000 [warn]: plugin/filter_parser.rb:69:rescue in block in filter_stream: invalid time format: value = 2017-04-27 12:01:58, error_class = ArgumentError, error = invalid strptime format - `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

The important part is this:

```
invalid time format: value = 2017-04-27 12:01:58, error_class = ArgumentError, error = invalid strptime format - `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

But I can't see how `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` doesn't match `2017-04-27 12:01:58`, or why this format would be invalid.

[according to this tool it should match](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%5E%5C%5B%28%3F%3Cmodule%3E%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D%2B%29%5C%5D%20%28%3F%3Ctime%3E.%2B%29%3A%20%28%3F%3Cmsg%3E.*%29%24&input=%5BMacaron%5D%202017-04-26%2016%3A54%3A26%3A%20Started%20GET%20%2F%20for%20172.20.0.0&time_format=%25Y-%25m-%25d%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S)

Comment: Make the time group not greedy: `(?<time>.+?):`

Comment: Maybe add a `\s*` after the time before the `:`

Comment: @toto if i do that then the whole pattern doesn't match anymore, that's reproducable here: http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%5E%5C%5B%28%3F%3Cmodule%3E%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D%2B%29%5C%5D+%28%3Ctime%3E.%2B%29%3A+%28%3F%3Cmsg%3E.*%29%24&input=%5BMacaron%5D+2017-04-26+16%3A54%3A26%3A+Started+GET+%2F+for+172.20.0.0&time_format=%25Y-%25m-%25d+%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S

Comment: @thechetan good idea, but that doesn't seem to be it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, there were some special characters to set colors in the log. Apparently when copy-pasting them into fluentular.herokuapp.com they did not get copied and that's why it worked there:

```
{"log":"[Macaron] \u001b[1;32m2017-04-27 12:34:07: Completed /node 200 OK in 1.163351ms\u001b[0m\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-04-27T12:34:07.953993591Z"}
```